# Convert TCP Data in with pipe to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

Sorry if the issue is not particularly clear (I am still a novice). I have a simple setup to get data from a mock feed and then convert the data to JSON. I can retrieve the data and display it but converting it to JSON has proved a bit tricky.

```
var completeData = '';
let client = net.createConnection({ port: 8282 }, () => {

client.write('Test Worked!\r\n');
});


client.on('data', (data) => {
// change buffer to string
let readData = data.toString();

// Merge response data as one string
completeData += readData += '\n';

// End client after server's final response
client.end();
});
```

This is the sample output for one packet below (Pipe delimited with some data escaped):

> |2054|create|event|1497359166352|ee4d2439-e1c5-4cb7-98ad-9879b2fd84c2|Football|Sky Bet League Two|\|Accrington\| vs \|Cambridge\||1497359216693|0|1|

I would like the pipes to represent keys/values in an object. The issue is that some of the values are escaped (e.g '\|' ). That kind of makes using the split function in Javascript difficult.

My question is there a way to get pipe delimited data from TCP packets and then convert them to a JSON object?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please see the [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help page. Asking readers to reverse engineer the proprietary syntax used in the data feed from non working code is like leaving out what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Made the question a bit simpler, Hopefully I get and answer this time. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { StringDecoder } = require("string_decoder");
let header = "";
const decoder = new StringDecoder("utf8");
let str = decoder.write(chunk); // chunk is your data stream
header += str;
header.replace(/s/, "");
var obj = JSON.parse(header);
console.log(obj);
```

While receiving data through tcp ip net npm package, we face trouble in parsing the continous stream of data. string_decoder is a npm package which can parse it into a json readable format. Also since the packets being received has a variable length so one can basically put a check on header.length to fetch only a complete set of object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: updated with detailed information on how the above code works